# create generic function which will be call at all routes

Tags: angularjs

In that function, I can get current controller and route value and according to current angular controller and route will call API which will return if user has access to that particular method or not.

I already did at server side using authorization attribute but need at client side.

Comment: Si le serveur du serveur de sécurité ne nécessite pas l'autorisation par méthode par devant. Utilisez simplement ng-if pour supprimer de DOM le Html qui appelle votre fonction angulaire. Store in you service your authorization for your user connected for use ng if in function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not provided any code example. I assume you have routing in the client side. And you want authentication/authorization during the routing process.

To do this you can observe the route before route started changing and can check the authenticity of the user there and permit or refuse the user accordingly.

**Sample code:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) { 
        // check here the user's authenticity and let the user go or redirect to another page    
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice i don't know this event. When your check your user for authorization, best practice is checked in your service where the user is stored or make a request in server side for checked your authorization ?

Comment: @nevradub yes, correct. You should do the authorization check in your service. And inject that service into the run method. Then you can call the method for checking authorization of the user. Making the http call here inside this event is not a good idea.

Comment: Actualy i redirect my user with my httpinterceptor. If my server return status code 401 the httpInterceptor redirect the user to login page. Isn't good process ?

Comment: It's difficult to say if it's a good practice or bad. What you have done is widely used process. But it completely depends on the scenario in which you have used the process.